# Finding larger number within a range

Tags: java

I have kept at these CodingBat questions and I ran into another problem.

The assignment was this:

> Given 2 positive int values, return the larger value that is in the range 10..20 inclusive, or return 0 if neither is in that range.

Some Examples:

- max1020(11, 19) → 19
- max1020(19, 11) → 19
- max1020(11, 9) → 11

My solution is:

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
    if (((a >= 10 && a <= 20) || (b >= 10 && b <= 20)) && a >= b) {
        return a;
    }

    if (((a >= 10 && a <= 20) || (b >= 10 && b <= 20)) && b >= a) {
        return b;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The code returned the correct output more than half of the time, but it did not work as expected in certain scenarios. The scenarios are when the input was (10,21),(21,10),(23,10).

This is weird because I explicitly excluded #>20 yet it returns 21, 21, and 23 respectively for the above three scenarios.

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: try writing your comparators as `(10=<a && a<=20)`, it makes it easier to read and spot errors.

Comment: after you check for range, you look for max of the two numbers

example 21,19  19 is within the range but 21 isn't, your if condition passes but you return max of the two which is 21. please note 21 is not in the range.

Comment: I don't know if you missed it while writing it here, but there should be an `else` before the second `if` . There are other problems, but you should resolve that one first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets walk through them.

```
(10,21):

if(((10 >= 10 && 10 <= 20) || (21>=10 && 21<=20)) && 10>=21)
  (((true and true) || (true and false)) && false)
  ((true) && false)
  false
```

Okay, not that one.

```
if(((10 >= 10 && 10 <= 20) || (21>=10 && 21<=20)) && 21>=10)
  (((true and true) || (true and false)) && false)
  ((true) and true)
  true

-> return 21
```

Okay why does that happen? Because your logic says "if either value is in the range, then return the larger value, EVEN IF the larger value is not in the range".

Instead, if a value is outside the range, don't even consider it. Here's one possible start:

```
if(a < 10 && a > 20) {
    // do something with only b. This is where you would return zero, too.
} else if(b < 10 && b > 20) {
    // do something with only a
} else {
    // do something with both
}
```

Comment: That's a good method of analysis I think I kind of get it now. Gonna try solving it one more time.

Comment: I ended up using a completely different method but thanks for the thorough response, helped me look at my logic chain a bit differently.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic basically says:

- If `a` or `b` is in range, and `a` is greater than or equal to `b`, then return `a`.
- If `a` or `b` is in range, and `b` is greater than or equal to `a`, then return `b`.
- Return 0.

So if `a` is in range but `b` is greater (and out of range), then `b` is still returned.

Change your logic to:

- If `a` is in range and `a` is greater than or equal to `b`, then return `a`.
- If `b` is in range and `b` is greater than or equal to `a`, then return `b`.
- Return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns the larger value if either value is in range.

Given the nature of these questions you should try a [test driven approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) to develop your method, this also assures that your code behaves as you intended it to. A test similar to what is below is probably what is testing you code when you submit it on CodingBat.

```
public class SandBox {
    public int max1020(int a, int b) {
        if (10 <= a && a <= 20) { // if a is in range
            if (a >= b || b > 20) { // if a is greater than B or B is out of range
                return a;
            }
        }

        //
        if (10 <= b && b <= 20) { // if b is in range
            return b;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Tests

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

public class SandBoxTest {
    SandBox sand;

    @Before
    public void given(){
        sand = new SandBox();
    }

    @Test
    public void testOne(){
        int i = sand.max1020(1, 2);
        assertThat(i, is(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void testTwo(){
        int i = sand.max1020(2, 1);
        assertThat(i, is(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void testThree(){
        int i = sand.max1020(5, 10);
        assertThat(i, is(10));
    }

    @Test
    public void testFour(){
        int i = sand.max1020(10, 5);
        assertThat(i, is(10));
    }

    @Test
    public void testFive(){
        int i = sand.max1020(11, 15);
        assertThat(i, is(15));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSix(){
        int i = sand.max1020(15, 11);
        assertThat(i, is(15));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSeven(){
        int i = sand.max1020(20, 23);
        assertThat(i, is(20));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEight(){
        int i = sand.max1020(23, 20);
        assertThat(i, is(20));
    }

    @Test
    public void testNine(){
        int i = sand.max1020(33, 25);
        assertThat(i, is(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void testTen(){
        int i = sand.max1020(25, 33);
        assertThat(i, is(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Boolean aInRange = (a >= 10 && a <= 20)

Boolean bInRange = (b >= 10 && b <= 20)

int max = 0;

if (aInRange && bInRange) {

    if(a >= b)
        max = a;
    else {
        max = b;
    }
} else if (!bInRange && aInRange) {
    max = a;
}
else if (bInRange && !aInRange) {
    max = b;
}
return max;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering how other people have solved and this is what I came up with, that includes ternary and a little of Math.abs + Math.max methods:

```java
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
  if(Math.abs(a - 15) <= 5 & Math.abs(b - 15) <= 5)
    return Math.max(a, b);
  if(Math.abs(a - 15) > 5)
    return Math.abs(b - 15) <= 5 ? b : 0;
  
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I've come up with as an algorithm to find the max value in array but with additional condition to be within a specific range. I think it is much more flexible and easier to read)

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
    int max = 0;
    int[] numbers= {a,b};
    for (int i  = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      if (numbers[i] > max &&  numbers[i] >=10 && numbers[i] <=20 ) {
        max = numbers[i];
      }
    }
    return max;

}
```